# Are there 3.5mm male to male flash sync cables?

Tags: flash, cables, sync

I am really going out of my way to try to find such a piece of gear in the most common shops but I can literally not find it, that I felt the need to come here and ask for help.

So I wanted to ask if this is a thing at all that exists. A flash sync cable that at both ends has a 3.5mm male connector, like the image bellow.

[image: 3.5mm male to male flash sync cable]

Or if I have to use some adapter to unite 2 PC SYNC's at one end, in order to use the 3.5mm in the other ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't find it specifically as a sync cable because the 3.5mm plugs that are used for flash sync are the same plugs used for mono audio cables.

You can use either mono or stereo audio cables with 3.5mm connectors for flash sync if you're connecting 3.5mm jacks together. The extra ring on the plug for stereo cables won't make any difference; the tip is still sync, and the base is still ground. That's all you need for a sync connection.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion, your cable needs are likely solved using audio cables. I think a 3.5mm male to 3.5mm male audio connector will do this trick.